# Php, MySql Join two tables and show all records with and without relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I've been breaking my head to figure out this query:

I have two tables:

```
Labels

id      name
====================
1       Inbox
2       Sent
3       Trash


Messages

id      label_id    user_id     name                    status                  
===============================================================
1       1           1           My First Message        1
2       1           1           My Second Message       1
3       2           1           My Third Message        1
4       0           1           My Fourth Message       1
5       0           1           My Fifth Message        1
```

and here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  m.name,
  m.id,
  m.label_id,
  l.name AS labelname
FROM
  `Messages` m 
  LEFT JOIN `Labels` l 
    ON l.id = m.label_id 
WHERE m.user_id = 1 
  AND m.status = 1;
```

The desired result is to show all labels regardless of matching message label_id

something like:

```
Inbox
=================
My First Message
My Second Message
==================

Sent
=================
My Third Message
=================

Trash
=================

=================
My Fourth Message
My Fifth Message
=================
```

As you can see the last two messages dont have any label_id, but I still want to show them at the end as well as Trash label which currently does not have anything assigned to it.

Comment: Your query should be fine.  What problem are you facing?

Comment: Also, what driver do you use? mysqli, pdo or mysql?

Comment: I'm using PDO driver, and I only get the first 3 records, the ones with label_id 0 are ignored.

Comment: Your query return all the records: check [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9124d/1). Use `->rowCount()` to check this.

Comment: maybe your real query has a “typo”? Like `WHERE m.label_id = 1` ?

Comment: I will double check for any typos, but how do I display Trash label as well. SQLite Fiddle you've created only show inbox and send labels.

Comment: In your sample there are not messages labeled as “Trash” (id=3) :/

Comment: See this [other example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2760/1) (same query)

Comment: That's correct I just edited my original question. I would like to display all of the labels regardless of any records assigned under them.

Comment: Your second example does not help, since there is record now assigned under trash lablel

Comment: Yes, but my second example is precent to your edit :)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain right. I want to display everything from both tables. even id label_id is 0. That include all messages and all labels

Comment: So you want to emulate a full join in MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
(
         SELECT  m.name, m.id, m.label_id, l.name AS labelname
           FROM  `Messages` m
      LEFT JOIN  `Labels` l   
             ON  l.id = m.label_id 
          WHERE  m.user_id = 1 
            AND  m.status = 1
)
UNION
(
         SELECT  m.name, m.id, m.label_id, l.name AS labelname
           FROM  `Labels` l
      LEFT JOIN  `Messages` m   
             ON  l.id = m.label_id AND m.user_id = 1 AND m.status =1
)
```

<kbd>**[sqlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9124d/8)**</kbd>

Use `UNION` to merge original result with results from *inverted* `LEFT JOIN`.

Please note different `ON` condition: using `WHERE` in second `SELECT` cause fake result.